# While loop with two conditionals

Tags: python

Can't seem to figure out why this two conditional while loop is not working. It should iterate over JSON until it finds one where both 'producer' = producer given & transactions list is not empty.

It seems to be treating it as an OR, because to stops as soon as transactions are not empty.

```
# Performs a get info and looks for producer name, if found returns head_block num.
def get_testnetproducer_cpustats(producer):
    # Get current headblock from testnet
    current_headblock = headblock("testnet")
    # Set producer to random name
    blockproducer = "nobody"
    transactions = []
    while producer != blockproducer and len(transactions) == 0:
        currentblock = getblock(current_headblock)
        print(currentblock)
        transactions = currentblock['transactions']
        # Set producer of current block
        blockproducer = currentblock['producer']
        print(blockproducer)
        # Deduct 1 from current block to check next block
        current_headblock = current_headblock - 1
    else:
        return print(current_headblock)
```

Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{'timestamp': '2020-08-16T20:33:11.000', 'producer': 'waxtribetest', 'confirmed': 0, 'previous': '029abe7da7da6691681eb9e9c6310532ed313a93dca25026f7f3059d2765177f', 'transaction_mroot': '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'action_mroot': '08bc38e7a4f1a832c3f9986e9c6553add7bbef8f0cfbe274772684b4f9d9a1a1', 'schedule_version': 4418, 'new_producers': None, 'producer_signature': 'SIG_K1_JzwAkDxatuPKBYVfP718JmNMTt5YGAR1E9Z5bBB4T3HtJxvDZq6SZU7HdjNK5SLigSAByWesPmPRjznWPF634czzRtbVwJ', 'transactions': [], 'id': '029abe7ec71e2af243c499b22036c350143d46054dec1659b4c3847650d7a3d2', 'block_num': 43695742, 'ref_block_prefix': 2996421699}
```

Comment: Your while loop will execute the code as long as **both** conditions are true. If one if false then the whole condition evaluates to false and the loop stops.

Comment: What @ShimonCohen means is: use `or` instead of `and`

Comment: Yes, thank you @barny :)

Comment: gosh, how did I get that wrong. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As @barny noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441776/while-loop-with-two-conditionals#comment112182645_63441776), use `or` instead of `and`:

```
while producer != blockproducer or len(transactions) == 0:
```